# Is it possible to cause one's autotitan to go nuclear?

Tags: titanfall

[Nuclear Ejection](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/635381-titanfall/68779694) seems to require that a pilot be in the cockpit in order for the nuclear explosion to trigger, if the titan is controlled by a player.
[image: Nuclear Ejection]
However, perhaps there is some configuration or method of making one's autotitan go nuclear?

Like autoeject? Though that still involves ejection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**

According to a response I got to this [question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/titanfall/comments/3p89hb/is_it_possible_to_cause_ones_autotitan_to_go/):

> Nope, it's triggered by the pilot ejecting. While it would make sense
>   from a design standpoint on the titan manufacturer's part. for game
>   balancing, it is not possible because this would make it way too
>   overpowered